# Cannot access 'forheader' before initialization

Tags: node.js, jwt

I m trying to verify the token from the header but it shows me this error.

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'forheader' before initialization

the error appear in line that I mention at the command inside first verification method.

```
function verfiytoken(req, res, next) {
    const forheader = req.headers['authorization'];
    //verfication 
    if (typeof forheader !== 'undefined') {

        //the app crashed here in next line and shows error.

        const hed = forheader.split(' ');
        const forheader = hed[1];
        console.log(forheader);
        req.token = forheader;
        next();
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(403);
    }
}
```

```
router.post("/sickers/filter/test", verfiytoken, cors(), (req, res) => {
    jwt.verify(req.token, (err, data) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
        else {
            res.json(data);
        }
    })
});
```

thanks.